# getting message open file security warning on remoteapp

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, remoteapp, windows-terminal-services

I have an app published on Windows 2008R2 remoteapp.

I am getting this message:

[image]

This is how I have the setup of the drive:

```
Local rdp machine is called rdpvm.

//rdpvm/shared/company1   = i:
//rdpvm/shared/company2   = i:
//rdpvm/shared/company3   = i:
```

And each one of these directories is mapped to the idrive per the GPO assigned to their Organization.

I tried to solve this with a group policy but it's just not working.

[image]

I tried several variations to see if I could get it to work.

[image]

I did run `gpupdate /force` after the change.

The funny thing is, one company worked fine, even before I made any changes and the other two have never worked. I have compared the gpo and I see no differences that would suggest why this is happening. This was all setup within the past week.

Anyone have any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

I tried these also just cause I am desparate:

```
\\rdpvm
\\192.168.1.34
http://192.168.1.34
```